# Scrollbar is not showing in ScrolledForm

Tags: java, layout, eclipse-plugin, swt, rcp

I am using `ScrolledForm` and using its property `setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true)` but still I am not getting scroll bar always.

Please count the reason: I want scroll bar to show always. I have used its `reFlow(true)` also by thinking problem in layout but it still not work.

```
formToolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
        form = formToolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);
        form.setText("scrolled from");
        form.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
        form.setFont(fontTahoma8Normal);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        form.getBody().setLayout(layout); 
GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL
                | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING
                | GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
        form.getBody().setLayoutData(data);
        return form;
```

Comment: Just a note: Using the `GridData` constants like `FILL_HORIZONTAL` is [not recommended](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html#FILL_HORIZONTAL).

Comment: @Baz Even i tried simple griddata with widthHint but it also not work

Comment: That's why I wrote _"Just a note"_, because it's not a solution to your question but rather a hint to good coding style.